# How to resize a silverlight object?

Tags: css, silverlight

I am trying to make Silverlight object responsive to browser size changes. I tried doing it in CSS providing the object with an id, and I have also changed width and height values to both `auto` and `%`. The documentation is vague, but says that is permitted, so I am wondering why doesn't it work?

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
                    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="980px" height="500px">
                      <param name="source" value="SmoothStreamingPlayer.xap"/>
                      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
                      <param name="background" value="white" />
                      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
                      <param name="InitParams" value="selectedcaptionstream=textstream_eng,mediaurl=http://cam.shockradio.co.uk/studiolive.isml/manifest" />
                      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
                          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
                      </a>
                    </object>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things should go wrong.

Do you want your Silverlight object go full scream?

1. You should set attribute for you HTML body with css:

```html
<style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #wrapper {
            min-height: 100%;
        }
</style>
```

2. User percentage to fit your object:

Answer (score 0):

We use something like:

`<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">`

to make our silverlight control fill the div. Percentage doesn't appear to be a supported value, according to html5 spec, but it sure works ...